# Angular 2 table not displaying properly on mobile device

Tags: angular, angular-material, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I am building a web app using Angular Material/ NgBootstrap/ Bootstrap 4.

I have a table where the user can search for data within a date range and the data is then displayed to the user in a table.

It all works fine in my desktop environment as shown in the following image where 12 sets of data is displayed and I can scroll down

[image: desktop]

However, for my mobile device, the view gets cut off and I can not see any data from the table

[image: mobile]

Have anyone experienced something like this where the behaviour on mobile device is off for Angular 2 app or perhaps bootsrap 4 apps?

Below are the code that I am using to display the table

```
<table *ngIf="myArray.length > 0 && !isLoading" class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Hours</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of myArray" (click)="onRowClick(pastApproval)">
        <td>{{data.firstName}} {{data.lastName}}</td>
        <td>{{data.workDate_epoch}</td>
        <td>{{data.totalHours}}</td>
        <td>{{data.status}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Note. If I use the chrom browser on my phone, it shows one row out of the 12. Kinda different to what shows here which I believe is from safari (opened from facebook link)

Comment: It's obviously some problem with the css. Attach your phone to the PC and check the chrome developer tools and try to find the css which makes the problem.

Comment: I never knew you could debug via phone. Would you mind sharing how to achieve that or perhaps a link to the guide? Thanks

Comment: Yes sure, here is the link: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Answer (score 0):

It was a CSS problem. Once I changed the css for the container to

```
height: 100%;
```

to

```
display:block; 
overflow:auto;
```

the problem disappears